# Nginx Logging parsing via Hive using SerDe

Tags: regex, hadoop, nginx, hive

I'm currently parsing a customized nginx log and I'm using the current hive script:

```
add jar s3://my-bucket-foo/hive-serde-0.13.1.jar;
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
set mapred.compress.map.output=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec;

DROP TABLE nginx_logs ;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE nginx_logs (
IP STRING,
`Timestamp` STRING,
Verb STRING,
URL STRING,
HTTPVersion STRING,
RequestProcessingTime STRING,
ReceivedBytes STRING,
URLReferer STRING,
UserAgent STRING,
MSISDN STRING,
XCALL STRING,
ResponseCode STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
```

<strike>"input.regex" = "(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\s+-\s+-\s+[(\d{2}/[a-z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+)-\d{4}]\s+\"(GET)(.+)(http/1.1\")\s+(\d{1,}.\d{3})\s+(\d+)\s+\"([^\"]+)\"\s+agent[\"([^\"]+)\"]\s+-\s+.\s+msisdn[([^]]+)]\s+xcall[([^]]+)]\s+(\d{1,})/gmi"</strike>

```
"input.regex" = "(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})\\s+-\\s+-\\s+\\[(\\d{2}\\/[a-z]{3}\\/\\d{4}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s+)-\\d{4}\\]\\s+\"(GET)(.+)(http\\/1\\.1\")\\s+(\\d{1,}\\.\\d{3})\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+agent\\[\"([^\"]+)\"\\]\\s+-\\s+\\.\\s+msisdn\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\s+xcall\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\s+(\\d{1,}).*"
    )

LOCATION 's3n://my-bucket/EMRInput/';
```

A few log lines and a example of working on a browser is here: http://regex101.com/r/tW8yT5/1
Sample line:

```
192.168.0.143 - - [25/Sep/2014:19:17:40 -0300]  "GET /adserver/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=4512&campaignid=374&zoneid=40&loc=1&cb=2b674aefb7 HTTP/1.1" 0.000  43 "http://wap.tim.com.br/html5/" Agent["Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; pt-br; LG-E467f Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"] - . msisdn[-] xcall[552199999955] 200
```

According to the **regexp101**, there are 12 matching groups:
[image: Matching Groups]

but whenever I execute the query:

<strike>select * from nginx_logs limit 10;</strike>

I get an error telling me that Number of matching groups isn't matching the number of columns.

```
hive> select * from nginx_logs limit 10;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
Time taken: 0.036 seconds
```

I've just double escaped the \ (backslash) and now instead of error I get:

```
hive> select * from nginx_logs limit 1;
OK
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.037 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning more how SerDe and Hive proccess the regex I was considering only one IP on the first matching group:

```
(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})
```

That would work for most of the cases, except those which had two or more ip's (proxied etc), so

```
200.222.108.241, 200.222.108.241, 200.222.108.241 - - [04/Oct/2014:06:30:48 -0300]  "GET /wml/redirect/jogos.wml HTTP/1.1" 0.000  154 "-" Agent["SAMSUNG-GT-E2222L/1.0 NetFront/4.1 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1"] - . msisdn[-] xcall[-] 302
```

Wouldn't work and give us a lot of headache. The solution came really fast, by using a group to match everything from the beginning up till the dash (-):

```
([^-]*)\\s+-\\s+-\\s+\\[(\\d{2}\\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\\/\\d{4}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s+)-\\d{4}\\]\\s+\"(GET)(.+)(HTTP\\/1\\.1\")\\s+(\\d{1,}\\.\\d{3})\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+Agent\\[\"([^\"]+)\"\\]\\s+-\\s+\\.\\s+msisdn\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\s+xcall\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\s+(\\d{1,}).*
```

Testing in a Java main program, it works like a charm:

Match ? true

```
Group 1: 200.222.108.241, 200.222.108.241, 200.222.108.241
Group 2: 04/Oct/2014:06:30:48 
Group 3: GET
Group 4:  /wml/redirect/jogos.wml 
Group 5: HTTP/1.1"
Group 6: 0.000
Group 7: 154
Group 8: -
Group 9: SAMSUNG-GT-E2222L/1.0 NetFront/4.1 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1
Group 10: -
Group 11: -
Group 12: 302
```

and voi lá, I'm now able to query it.